# Spring Security 3.1.3 @EnableWebSecurity

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm having trouble finding which package contains @EnableWebSecurity in Spring Security 3.1.3. I've added core, config, web and ldap security packages, but the annotation remains unavailable.  Has it been replaced by another annotation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think java config support is not yet released with Spring Security, but available as a separate module in [spring-security-javaconfig](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security-javaconfig/blob/master/README.md). See instructions in the linked page about how to include the jar into your maven build.

Comment: Thanks, I had glanced over that section and went straight to the examples.  It works now.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and was able to solve it by adding "spring-boot-starter-security" as a dependency in build.gradle as mentioned in the spring "Getting Started" guide available @
https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/