# EnableWebSecurity cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-security

[The screenshot of error is here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWTvM.png)I am new to spring security and was trying to implement this tutorial http://websystique.com/spring-security/angularjs-basic-authentication-using-spring-security/

But my dependencies are not getting resolved as none of the class of prefix org.springframework.security.config.* is getting resolved to a type
 I have already included 3 jars:

```
spring-security-web-3.1.2-RELEASE.jar 
spring-security-core-3.1.2-RELEASE.jar
spring-security-config-3.1.2-RELEASE.jar
```

still the error is coming. Is there any other jar I am missing?
NOTE-I am not using maven

Comment: this is strange, you should see that package including spring-security-config. But why are you using 3.1.2 version? There are newer versions. I tried with 4.1.2 and i see the package config. http://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/security/spring-security/

Comment: @amicoderozer I am using spring 3 so opted for version 3 jars . But regardless of version it should work I guess.

Comment: do you have errors in the console? could you post your classpath? is difficult to guess what's wrong without other clues.

Comment: @amicoderozer Due to lack of reputations I can not upload image but I have included a link which will redirect you to error image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in this answer

[Spring Security 3.1.3 @EnableWebSecurity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16105844/spring-security-3-1-3-enablewebsecurity)

java config support is not released with Spring Security 3.1.2. I suggest to update spring security to a newer version. Download version 3.2.9 and you will find the missing packages.

This is the link to the spring repository:

http://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/security/spring-security/3.2.9.RELEASE/

Answer (score 8):

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-security -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```